# Is it possible to get numbered sections in beamer template using rmarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pandoc

According to [documentation](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf) (p. 5) it is *not* possible to number sections in PDF presentations (beamer template) using `rmarkdown` (at least not as `pandoc` argument).

More precisely, the option `number_section` is not available for `beamer_presentations` (according to documentation cited above).

However, as TeX does generally support this feature, there should be a way.

Is there a (straight-forward, hopefully) way to achieve this?

Example code (does *not* run):

```
--- 
title: "test"
output: 
   beamer_presentation:
     number_section: true
---


# Topic A
kdsfj

# Topic B
sdjfkl
```

Comment: Notice though, that `#` creates a new slide or more precisly a new `frame` environment and not a section.

Answer (score 4):

You can experiment with customizing the beamer template and include it through your YAML header.

```
--- 
title: "My Presentation"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: head.tex
    toc: true
---

# Section A

## Topic a
Bla

## Topic b
Bla

# Section B

## Topic c
Bla
```

In my *head.tex* I customized the frametitle and added the section numbers to the TOC as well:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\thesection \hspace{0.2cm} \insertframetitle}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]